# How to auto increment mysql Limit command in php

Tags: php, mysql, limit

i need to display mysql table rows one at a time for this i am using in php:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from table limit 0,1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "First Name:" . $row['First'] . " " . "Last Name:" . $row['Last'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I need to display one row at a time, but display every new row on every php executinon, like first user gets to see first "firstname, lastname" second anonymous user on executing the page gets to see second "firstname, lastname" from the database.

this gives an error :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from voucher limit '$count',1");
```

(i included $count to the parameters)

On execution it just displays the first row every time. I need modification to it that whenever the code is executed it returns a new row value. For example, first time it will output first row, on seond execution of the script it outputs second row and so on..

i am using php5, mysql on ubuntu server.

Please help.

Comment: Just remove the limit altogether

Comment: Try with a `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways : 
The first one is to save the increment value somewhere. I dont know how do you pass it or when and how you exsecute it, but it they run run separately each time (e.g. runs via a cron job or terminal), you can save the value in a simple file or memchache.

First way :

```
$offset = file_get_contents('my_counter.txt');
$offset++;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from table limit " . (int) $offset . ",1");
file_put_contents('my_counter.txt', $offset);
```

The next one is to save the the last id from your row:

```
$lastID = file_get_contents('my_counter.txt');
if($lastID == "") // First call and no last id
    $lastID = 0;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from table WHERE ID > " . (int) $lastID . " limit 0,1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "First Name:" . $row['First'] . " " . "Last Name:" . $row['Last'];
     $lastID = $row['ID']; // Your autoincrement row
}
file_put_contents('my_counter.txt', $lastID);
```

I hope I understood your question right and this helps you.

Comment: Martin how to i get to execute this part:
    echo $lastID;
     file_put_contents('/var/www/my_counter.txt', $lastID);
after a user click on    <input type="submit" value="submit">

Comment: Just add the code on your form submition action :) Eg. 

If we have :

<form action="?action=save_user" method="post">
// your inputs here
</form>

In your action you will have 

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'save_user') {
   // DO YOUR SAVE HERE
}

Comment: i have a form field described as:
<form  method="post" action="myaction.php">
how can i add multiple actions and should i save it in the file containing this form or creat a new file to verify the action.

Comment: You can check this url :

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/handling-multiple-submits-in-a-single-form-with-php/

Comment: basically i am generating orderwise the 'name' and 'father name' and giving the output to a variable and then putting it in a form input that is then linked to an action file. i have put this code that we discussed on the same file that has the form. the problem is that on every refresh the $lastID gets incremented. is there any way that on page refresh it does not get incremented but on that form submit it should or someother way.

Comment: Check if you have a post like 

if($_POST) 

this way it will increment only on post submit

Comment: Martin, how can i put all the code that you have given me in an input feild? So that it may be processed by the POST global operator.

Comment: You cant. You can process the code on the form submit in your action

Comment: Thats Right. I did just that. Thanks!

Comment: insert into voucher (mobile,date) values (3331234567,10102014) where id='1';
but it gives error:1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where id='1'' at line 1

the table values where i want to insert are NULL. and has auto increament id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "First Name:" . $row['First'] . " " . "Last Name:" . $row['Last'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: He wants a new record to be displayed every time the code runs.

Comment: This do the same Right?

Comment: No this displays all records in the table. He want 1 new record/load

Comment: Im not a php programmer so im not sure. this wont increment the value i think. Its based on whenever php code executes so i think this will give the same record all the time because its just one refresh. I think the best is to just use `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the data to be retrived when `php code` runs, you need to count the loop inside your code and increment the value like below.

If you want to loop, you need to increment the `0` in `LIMIT 0,1`

Something like this in a loop

```
LIMIT " . $loopcount . ",1
LIMIT " . $loopcount . ",1
LIMIT " . $loopcount . ",1
```

Im not a php programmer so i dont know the exact code.

You could if you just need a random and not the next, use  `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`.

This just gives a random record, and you wont go outside of the table as it always selects one record from the table.

It will affect your performance a bit if you have a big table. But you will always get a record. If you just loop `LIMIT " . $loopcount . ",1` you run the chance of trying to select outside of the table scope. If you have 100 rows, and you try `LIMIT 101,1` you will get a empty recordset.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want to achieve, how can i do that in php?